# How to combine 2 Decorators to process files together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend

How to combine 2 Decorators to process files together, u can see we need 2 decorator for the file, and it's look so verbose

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
      console.log(file)
    }
```

How can I combine UseInterceptors with UploadedFile ???
Maybe like it:

```
async upload(@UploadedFile(ImageUpload('file', MultiOptions)) file: 
Express.Multer.File) {
  console.log(file)
}
```

I tried converting UseInterceptors to ImageUploadInterceptor and it's look like good.

Fisrtly, I make the function can custom all field i want to upload file, and then just return to UseInterceptors look like this, please open the picture

```
const { MEGABYTE, SIZE_NUM } = IMAGE_COMPRESS_CONFIG;

const FileInterceptorWithDefaultLimit = (imageField: string) => {
  return FileInterceptor(imageField, {
    limits: {
     fileSize: MEGABYTE * SIZE_NUM,
    },
    fileFilter: (
      req: Request,
      file: Express.Multer.File,
      callback: (error: Error | null, acceptFile: boolean) => void
    ) => {
      const allowedMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 
'image/webp'];
      if (allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
         callback(new BadRequestException('Invalid file type! Only JPG, 
JPEG, and PNG are allowed.'), false);
      }
    },
  });
};

 export const ImageUploadInterceptor = (imageField: string) => {
    return UseInterceptors(FileInterceptorWithDefaultLimit(imageField));
   };
```

And it was successful... just for UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file')), Look:

```
@ImageUploadInterceptor('file')
    async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
      console.log(file)
    }
```

But it's not all I want, u can see

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. There's not a way to combine a method decorator and a parameter decorator into a single decorator. That's just not something that Typescript allows with its decorators.